# Call function in external library from Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

We have a script placed on our site that is used to generate pop-up's/modals.

The modal can be invoked by calling

```
ModalObject.Triggeronclick(someModalId)
```

However, I cannot call this function from the Angular controller (and I need access to data and logics within the controller, to trigger the call).

I have tried calling

```
window.ModalObject.Triggeronclick(someModalId)
```

... but I get:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'triggerOnclick' of undefined".
```

How can I call this function from my app controller?

Comment: I'd suggest not mixing angular and non-angular resources. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ has lots of features including modals. It's all created with Angular and bootstrap. There are also other options available to you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-modal-service

Comment: Seems that `ModalObject` is undefined on `window`. Are you loading the library in the main window before angularjs libraries?

Comment: @EibergDK, please take a look at my answer. As long as the ModalObject is on the window object then best practice for Angular is to wrap it in a service that can be injected. If this helps you please take a moment to accept my answer and upvote. And if you have any other questions please feel free to ask. Always happy to help!

Comment: @Igor, the external library is loaded before the Angular libraries, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using your `ModalObject` instead of an angular specific modal resource, Then you should create a factory/service that returns `$window.ModalObject` - $window being the angular injected window object. Then you can inject that factory/service into your controller.

```
    app.factory('modalObject', ($window) => {
        return $window.ModalObject
    })
```

Assuming the ModalObject is available on the window object.

Then inject `modalObject` into your controller.

However, there are other options that are specifically angular modals:

- https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
- https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+modal+npm&oq=angular+mo&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0j69i59j69i57j69i60.1372j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the resource to the index.html and access global variables with

```
(<any>window).document
```

where you would normally just call

```
document
```